# Angular2: How to use on the frontend "crypto.pbkdf2Sync" function from node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, cryptography

There is a function [`crypto.pbkdf2Sync()` in `node.js` API](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2sync_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest) and I whant to use it in my Angular2 project.

I tried to import it and use it. Project compiles with no error, but in browser I get an error:

> TypeError: **webpack_require**.i(...) is not a function
>       at createHashSlow (hash.ts:4)

Here is the `hash.ts` module:

```
import { pbkdf2Sync } from 'crypto';
import { CONFIG } from '../config';

export function createHashSlow(password, salt) {
  return pbkdf2Sync(
    password,
    salt,
    CONFIG.crypto.hash.iterations,
    CONFIG.crypto.hash.length,
    'SHA1'
  ).toString('base64');
};
```

What did I do wrong? How to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_determining_if_crypto_support_is_unavailable) module is based on OpenSSL that is not available in the browser

> The crypto module provides cryptographic functionality that includes a set of wrappers for OpenSSL's hash, HMAC, cipher, decipher, sign and verify functions.

I suggest to use WebCryptographyApi that is available in all modern browsers. See an example here [Angular JS Cryptography. pbkdf2 and iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459020/angular-js-cryptography-pbkdf2-and-iteration/40468218#40468218)